# Any audit trail of when Windows Server 2008 Automatic Updates settings are changed?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-event-log, automatic-updates

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine that keeps on rebooting even though I tell it not to do so after automatic updates are installed. I am certain that *no* group policy is applied to this server to produce this result, and yet, it keeps changing from "Download but let me install" to "Automatically install and reboot," roughly speaking.

I have a *strong* hunch that somebody may be changing this setting back without realizing the potential damage it can cause, but I've no way to prove it.

Is there any way to determine *who* changed Automatic Updates settings and/or *when* they were changed?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a little late but I also had a reason to want to know this. An event is logged when the setting is changed but it's a little vague and the user is just logged as SYSTEM but you may be able to tell when it was changed. Create a custom view in event viewer and limit it to events from source WindowsUpdateClient. When the settings are changed an information event is created stating "There has been a change in the health of Windows Update."